# Download and install new Amiga Forever games

Tags: backwards-compatibility, technical-issues, amiga

The site http://www.amigaforever.com/ offers a product that I've installed, but it has limited games on it. Has anyone successfully downloaded and installed new games for this system? It's all completely legal and clean to do so, this isn't one of those emulator hacks. And in any case, I already bought Marble Madness, Artic Fox, Shadow of the Beast and Kingdoms of England 20 years ago, I just want to play them again. :-)

Comment: This reads more like an advertisement than an actual question.

Comment: @george - how would you prefer it reworded? i'm not advertising, i'm just trying to keep from having the question deleted for asking for illegal downloads of stuff, as several other amiga posts have been recently... and the interface is specific -- just because one may download an amiga game on one platform doesn't mean it will work with amigaforever...

Answer (score 2):

The Amiga Forever website has a page describing [where to get more games for Amiga Forever](http://www.amigaforever.com/games/). It includes links to websites which supply Amiga games with the copyright holder's permission.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Jonathan Drain's answer, note that if you use FS UAE (http://fs-uae.net) as your emulator, you can set it up to connect to the Open Amiga Game Database (OAGD, cf http://oagd.net).

When that is done, the emulator is then capable to connect to sites which offer legal downloads of some of the games contained in the database.